# regular expression for multiple ip address

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in php like this.

```
$str = "192.168.10.1;10.192.10.10;" //Contains repeated ip addresses
```

I want to validate it using regular expression by preg_match function but i am unable to create the regular expression for it.
I have created following :`/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\;\z/`

but this only validate till first ';' not after that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/rZ1kU5/1)

Comment: Good article why regex isn't the best solution for this kind of problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/22/603788.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an RegEx solution but works fine using [ip2long](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) function:

```
<?php
$str = "192.168.10.1;10.192.10.10;256.10.10.10";

$ips = explode(";", $str);

foreach ($ips as $ip) {
    if (strlen($ip) > 0  && ip2long($ip) === false) {
        echo $ip." is not valid.";
    }
}
```

Comment: what if string would be like this 192.168.10.1;10.192.10.10;256.10.10.10;172.168.10.10;10.192.1.200;

Comment: Your link send to the german version of php.net

Comment: @aadi: It will work for any length of ip string to validate.
also your last string makes the script returns: `256.10.10.10 is not valid.` [try it out here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0f4239da7f5a5e4b4226294f0343494fec77216d)

Comment: @cyrbil: changed to english one

Comment: @aadi If you had tested my example, you had seen that it works also for this string of concated ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`. `preg_match_all()` catches all patterns found on the subject string..

and you should also remove the `^` in your pattern since it will just match patterns at the beginning of the subject string.

I have tried this code and worked perfectly:

```
<?php
  $str = "192.168.10.1;10.192.10.10;";
  $pattern = "/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\;/";
  $match = array();
  preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $match);

  print_r($match);
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 192.168.10.1;
        [1] => 10.192.10.10;
    )

)
```